# How can i build IPA and install on iPhone by URL [React-Native]

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I used to install some application by URL on iPhone
**with out publish to store.**

But my iOS application developed by react native can i do this ?
it's have node module.
something like bundle apk on android ?

need step by step thank you. :D

Comment: You can build IPA with xcode

Comment: Okay now I can publish to store.  But how can i create host for install by url

Comment: Already have ipa on my iPhone

Comment: is it on Applestore?

Comment: If it is released you can use URL in anywhere like...
Example of Temple Run App..
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/temple-run/id420009108?mt=8#

On click of URL it will redirect to applestore.

Comment: @metalwake check my answer

Comment: I think my method is with out publish to store. 
I used to install application by url (without store)
How can I do this .

Answer (score 0):

If your app is belongs to enterprise edition Then you can host it in your server else you can install via cloud like DropBox..,

> Diawi is only for testing purpose.it will be expired in 7 days.

[Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) is a tool for developers to deploy Development and In-house applications directly to the devices.

1. Upload the iOS or Android application.
2. Send the link to your testers, clients, friends or even use it yourself.
3. Open the link in the browser on the device and click on install.

It works for iOS and Android.

Comment: Diawi we can use for testing purpose throughout the world

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can .

First you need to build your project with selection of Generic or Device in Run target settings.

1. After successful build you can check you .app in **Product folder**.
2. Right click on that and select **show in finder** option.
3. After that you need to that .app file to itunes's application section .
4. After process you will able to your application's icon, Right click on that select **show in finder** option again.
5. Now simply drag that .ipa file to [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) .
6. After completion of upload you need to  click on send .
7. Copy that url and send to client .

Comment: Can i drop my .ipa on google drive and share it's to other ?

Comment: You can drop ipa on google drive . but they needs itunes for install that ipa in device . in diawi they can install app through url.